# How to get timezone offset between UTC and iPhone - Swift 4.2?

Tags: swift, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm on **Swift 4.2**. I'm struggling trying to get the offset time between UTC and the one from my iPhone.

---

I have this code

```
extension TimeZone {
    func offsetFromGMT() -> String
    {
        let localTimeZoneFormatter = DateFormatter()
        localTimeZoneFormatter.timeZone = self
        localTimeZoneFormatter.dateFormat = "Z"
        return localTimeZoneFormatter.string(from: Date())
    }
}
```

---

```
func getCurrentTimeZone() -> String{
    return String (TimeZone.current.identifier)
}


var tzOffset = ""
let currentTimeZone = getCurrentTimeZone()
TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers.forEach({ timeZoneIdentifier in
    if let timezone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZoneIdentifier)
    {
        //print("\(timezone.identifier) \(timezone.offsetFromGMT())")
    
        if(timezone.identifier == currentTimeZone){
            tzOffset = timezone.offsetFromGMT()
        }
    }
})
```

---

## Result

If I do

```
print(tzOffset)
```

I got

```
-0500
```

Should it be `-5` since my currentTimeZone is `America/Montreal` ?

Can someone please give me a hints ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the current timezone, get the number of seconds from GMT and divide it by 3600.

```
TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT() / 3600    // -3 hs America/Sao_Paulo (current) Brazil
```

If you need more precision like fraction of hour as well just convert it to double before dividing it.

Answer (score 1):

it should be `-0500`.

[From the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9205:00)

The reason why it has 4 digits instead of one is because it is in a 24 hour format, and some time zones are measured in a half-hour distance from UTC

Comment: Is there a way to get it in a format of `-5` ? My Back End API is expected `-12` to `12` only. I don't have access to change that. 

Comment: @kyo Does your API handle timezones that are fractions of an hour off from UTC?